# Howto convert the lower 10bits of a uword into hex in C

Tags: c, hex, converters

I have the following function:

```
uword ADC_uwReadConv(void) {
  ADCIR = 0;
  return(ADDAT);
}
```

This functions returns a result of a AD conversion (of a C164CI). The lower 10 bits contain the conversion result while the upper 4 bits identify the converted analog channel.

Now, I have some questions:

- I have now idea what datatyp uword is. Would be great if someone could give me a detailed explanation.
- I need to convert the result into hex and I really don't know how to do this.

Comment: This is not standard C. You should give the exact standard you want to follow (C99 ?), and give the `#include` you are using, and the compiler you are using. I guess that `uword` is some `unsigned` (e.g. `unsigned short` or `unsigned int`)... With standard *C* you could `printf("%x\n", ADC_uwReadConv() & 0x3ff);` to print the lower 10 bits in hex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a 16bit microprocessor so the word size is 16bits. a uword is an Unsigned word; and in this case ranges from 0x0000 - 0xFFFF.

"Convert" the result is not necessarily the best choice of words. If u do need to display the lower 10 bits of the value you could use something like

```
printf("%x", ADC_uwReadConv()&0x3F)
```